# Uncaught ReferenceError: mapdispatchtoprops is not defined ReactJS Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, cart, react-props, shopping-cart

I am trying to build an cart to store items which i have fetched with the fakestore Api.
But somehow I get this RefereceError for an variable which I have already defined. Furthermore the addToCart method is not being used.

This is my Main file which I am using:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Skeleton from 'react-loading-skeleton';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addToCart } from '../redux/Shopping/shoppingActions';

const Product = ({productData, addToCart}) => {

const {id} = useParams();
const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

//fetch the clicked product 
useEffect(() => {
    const getProduct = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${id}`); 
        setProduct(await response.json());
        setLoading(false);
    }
    getProduct();
}, [id]);


const Loading = () => {
    return(
        <div className="loading">
            Loading...
        </div>
    );
};

const mapdispatchtoprops = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        addToCart: (id) => dispatch(addToCart(id))
    };
};

const ShowProduct = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <div className='productImage'>
                <img src={product.image} alt={product.title} height='400px' width='400px'/>
            </div>
            <div className='productText'>
                <h1 className='productTitle'>{product.title}</h1>
                <h4 className='productCategory'>{product.category}</h4>
                <p className='productRating'>Rating {product.rating && product.rating.rate}</p>
                    <i className='productRatingStars'></i>
                <h3 className='productPrice'>${product.price}</h3>
                <p className='productDescription'>{product.describtion}</p>
                <button className='addCart' onClick={()=>addToCart(productData.id)}>Add to Cart</button>
                <NavLink to='/cart' className='goCart'>Go to Cart</NavLink>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

return (
    <div>
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                {loading?<Loading/>:<ShowProduct/>}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

export default connect (null, mapdispatchtoprops)(Product);
```

Thats the file I am getting the "addToCart" from:

```
import * as actionTypes from './shoppingTypes'

export const addToCart = (itemID) => {
    return{
        type: actionTypes.ADD_TO_CART,
        payload: {
            id: itemID,
        }, 
    };
}; 
export const removeFromCart = (itemID) => {
    return{
        type: actionTypes.REMOVE_FROM_CART,
        payload: {
            id: itemID,
        }, 
    };
};
export const adjustQty = (itemID, value) => {
    return{
        type: actionTypes.ADJUDT_QTY,
        payload: {
            id: itemID,
            qty: value,
        }, 
    };
};
export const loadCurrentItem = (itemID, value) => {
    return{
        type: actionTypes.LOAD_CURRENT_ITEM,
        payload: {
            id: itemID,
            qty: value,
        }, 
    };
};
```

Comment: You've passed a decorated `addToCart` action creator to `Product` and didn't use it, and use the raw `addToCart` action creator in `ShowProduct`... assuming the first code snippet is all in the same file. Oh, wait... why are you declaring a React component inside another React component? `ShowProduct` should be declared on its own, outside of `Product`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared `mapdispatchtoprops` inside the `Product` component, so it's undefined in the outer file scope where you are trying to use it in the `connect` HOC. Move it outside `Product`.

```
const Product = ({ productData, addToCart }) => {
  ...
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addToCart
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Product);
```